# Error in export PNG canvas all div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

In localhost, it's works exported div to image, include image over another image. I need create dynamic ID card.

But, the local project its work perfect, but the project online, not worked

- I used guillotine for only zoom image and move
- My first image template is svg inside div as background image
- The name, job, number employee its show

```
var test = $(".test").get(0);
    $('.toCanvas').click(function(e) {
        html2canvas(test).then(function(canvas) {
            var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
            var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
            var img = Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvas, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            $('#save').click(function(e) {
                let type = 'png'; // image type
                w = canvasWidth;
                h = canvasHeight;
                Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, w, h, type, 'credencial');
            });
        });
    });
```

i tried different options, for example, generated image to php, save it, and after download, but  the problem its same, locally its work perfectly, but online not working

thanks